# How to exclude authors from get_pages()

Tags: pages, wp-admin

I am trying to filter the results for the wp_dropdown_pages function by author, here is what I have so far.

```
$dropdown_args = array(
            'post_type'        => $post->post_type,
            'exclude_tree'     => $post->ID,
            'selected'         => $post->post_parent,
            'name'             => 'parent_id',
            'show_option_none' => __('(no parent)'),
            'sort_column'      => 'menu_order, post_title',
            'echo'             => 0,
            'authors'          => '-11',
        );
wp_dropdown_pages( $dropdown_args );
```

When I try this the dropdown does not show up, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

this function does not take exclude author args. If you want to exclude a specific author and want to display all pages. Then you can do this easily by `WP_Query`.